# Folder has nothing in file explorer but still shows it has 16GB in Properties window. Not sure what is taking up that space

Tags: filesystems

As in the title, I have a folder with nothing in it when looking at the file explorer. When I look at the Properties window, it shows the folder has 16GB. What is this 16GB if nothing is in the folder?

Comment: Can you be more specific.  How about a screenshot?  How about using WinDirStat as an Administrator and submitting the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go into Options, View and toggle off "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" to see if there are any hidden files in the directory.